# How to change the Find result format in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

In earlier versions of Visual Studio, you could change the way that results from Find are presented by altering the value of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\{VSVersion}\Find\Find result format`. In particular, I would set it to `$f$e($l): $t\\r\\n` which removes the full path from the entry.

Making the same change to  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0\Find\Find result format` doesn't seem to do anything. Is there another way to address this in VS2017?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VS 2017 now uses private registry (see [Where does Visual Studio 2017 RC store its config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41119996/where-does-visual-studio-2017-rc-store-its-config)). One way to access it directly is from a running Visual Studio 2017 instance with my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension. For example, you can use the following C# command:

```
public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
{
    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
    {
        var key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(
            @"Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\" + DTE.Version + @"\Find");
        key.SetValue("Find result format", @"$f$e($l): $t\r\n");
    }
}
```