# Customize Find in Files results window in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2015 you could customise what was displayed in the Find in Files results window by editing the registry key at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Find (see blog post at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/01/03/customize-how-find-in-files-results-are-displayed-in-the-find-results-window/).

Visual Studio 17 does not have this key and, despite searching repeatedly over the past few months, I can find no way of controlling what is shown in the results window. This means long file paths take up most of the window space, making it very inconvenient to use. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43918053/how-to-change-the-find-result-format-in-visual-studio-2017 and https://visualstudioextensions.vlasovstudio.com/2017/06/29/changing-visual-studio-2017-private-registry-settings/

Comment: Thank you very much. Looks like what I need.